# How to assert duplicate record while updating or inserting record Test case for API in ruby on rails using fakeweb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

```
options = {:body => fixture_file("parse.xml"),:content_type => "application/xml",:status =>["200", "OK"]}
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, @url, options)
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(@url,:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))

should "cases should not insert duplicate record" do

      doc.xpath('//cases/case').each do |case|

      end
end
```

here inserting or updating record using `Model.find_or_initialize_by_id(case['ixBug'])`, how i should check this condition in test case by putting assertion?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check for duplicate records using model validations. It seems you're doing integration testing (that is useful to test controller responses and/or test that all the environment is working well).

it doesn't make sense to test data duplication there.